# How to convert RDD list of lists into one list in pyspark

Tags: list, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD object, a list of lists, that looks like this (omitted millions of sublists, only left 3 here)

```
my_tuples = [[('a','b'),('a','c')], 
             [('b','a'),('b','f'),('b','g')], 
             [('zzsx','c'), ('zzsx','q'), ('zzsx','m'), ('zzsx','ay'), ('zzsx','bbt')]]
```

and I want to convert it into a single list like this

```
my_list = [('a','b'),('a','c'), ('b','a'),('b','f'),('b','g'), 
           ('zzsx','c'), ('zzsx','q'), ('zzsx','m'), ('zzsx','ay'), ('zzsx','bbt')]
```

I can't use loops since `my_tuples` is an RDD object and the size of `my_tuples` is too large to do it. I'm new to spark, any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flatten it using `flatMap`:

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda l: l)
```

Since your elements are list, you can just return those lists in the function, as done in the example

```
[('a', 'b'),
 ('a', 'c'),
 ('b', 'a'),
 ('b', 'f'),
 ('b', 'g'),
 ('zzsx', 'c'),
 ('zzsx', 'q'),
 ('zzsx', 'm'),
 ('zzsx', 'ay'),
 ('zzsx', 'bbt')]
```